# What is "Hebrew letter form"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, aleph-bet-letters

Rabbi Michael L. Munk composed "The Wisdom of the Hebrew in the Hebrew Alphabet". Pg. 44 on Aleph he addresses the 'graphic form' of Aleph. He explains the aleph is a construct of two yuds and a vav. Elsewhere I have learned an opinion that Aleph is a construct of a yud and gimel (gimel likewise constructed of vav-yud).

Attempts to delve into Moshe Dodo ben Barzilai method of gematria called Mispar haBeka (where each letter of the Hebrew alphabet is "split" into its component letters and then these component letters are added up, giving a new sum to each letter) have struggled. It seems Gal Einai provides insight at least into construction, but no mention of what this is called nor does it provide a source for these interpretations.
https://inner.org/alefbeit/

What is this method of determining the 'construction' of a letter called in Hebrew-English?
Where can a list of all letters including sofit be referenced?

Comment: The link you cited is broken...also, who's Moshe Dodo ben Barzilai?

Comment: The whole section of the site is broken. Here's the [introduction](https://inner.org/alefbeit/alefbeit), but you'll need to strip out `.htm` if you're clicking the links.